# dplyr data frame tbl: incorrect reported column length

Tags: r

I came a across a problem with dplyr, which caused an error message when I used it in a survival analysis.  The root cause turned out to be that when a variable in a grouped data frame (or any object with class tbl_df) is referred to using [,] notation, it always reports a length of 1, even when the real length is greater than that.  Using the $x notation reports the correct length.

With a data frame, the following return the expected length of 32:

```
length(mtcars$mpg)
length(mtcars[ , "mpg"])
```

With a grouped data frame the $ notation returns 32, and all the rest using [] notation return a length of 1:

```
foo <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl)
length(foo$mpg)
length(foo[ , "mpg"])
length(foo[ ,  1])
VarName <- "mpg"
length(foo[ ,  VarName])
```

It is just the reported length that is incorrect The data itself is all there i.e.:

```
 head(foo[ , "mpg"])
```

The incorrect reported length leads to an error message in functions such as Surv(), which presumably include a length() check. This is obviously a very simplified example to illustrate. In the failed program I was using [ , VarName] notation inside a function to refer to a variable column.  The workaround is simply to convert the data from the offending Data Frame Tbl format to an ordinary data frame within the function.  Can anyone shed any light on why this happens?  It might save others wasting as much time as I have!

Comment: The data isn't exactly all there - it's inside a list. Consider `foo[, "mpg"][[1]]` versus `foo[, "mpg"]`: you see that in second, it's a list (i.e. run `typeof` on both). Compare with `typeof(mtcars[, "mpg"])`. This is because `dplyr` returns a `grouped_df` (see `dplyr:::group_by_.data.frame`) and not a straight `data.frame`. It emulates many, but not all, of the same capabilities - and has more. e.g. you cannot modify or drop a grouped column.

Comment: I maybe should have expanded on this a bit in the example, but the issue is not so much what can be done to a grouped_df,  but what can be done with the output of grouped operations (in my case to tabulate survival of groups).  If summarise cannot be used with a wide variety of functions that take a data frame as input, that rather limits its usefulness.  When used on a grouped data frame, summarise produces an object of class "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame", which rather surprisingly appears to cause problems with things as basic as standard R indexing. I'm afraid I'm going back to plyr!

Comment: Yes, that's fair. All operations in `dplyr` return a data frame, including column indexing. That's by design -- it's not a bug -- but it does mean that if you need the vector it'll trip you up.

Comment: Just to be even more precise about the issue, summarise uses tibbles, and standard R indexing does not always work with tibbles.  
`df2 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)`
`length(df2$x)`
`length(df2[,1])`
`length(df2[,"x"])`